# Updating state value on at a time using useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

The below code is giving me a warning :
A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
when I am changing either password or username.

I am not able to figure out why I am getting this error.
Can someone tell me why exactly i am getting this error....

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Login = () => {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState({ user: "", password: "" });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setLogin({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      User Name{" "}
      <input
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
        name="username"
        value={login.user}
      />
      Password{" "}
      <input
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="password"
        name="password"
        value={login.password}
      />
      <button>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the class component's `setState()`, setting the state in functional components with `useState()` doesn't merge the update object with the previous state. Setting the state with `useState()` replace the previous one. That is why the state in `useState()` can be arrays, objects, or primitives.

In your case, when you the state - `setLogin({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });`, you are replacing the entire state, and in effect remove the value of the other field. You should spread the previous value of the login state, and override just the value of the field that you are changing.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Login = () => {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState({ user: "", password: "" });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setLogin(login => ({ ...login, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      User Name{" "}
      <input
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
        name="user" // this should be user and not username
        value={login.user}
      />
      Password{" "}
      <input
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="password"
        name="password"
        value={login.password}
      />
      <button>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Login />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah my bad...I go it now. Thanks Ori